# Failed to execute python executable with arguments which contains # (hash) character using Java Process

Tags: java, python, bash, shell, unix

Per question heading, not able to execute the command below successfully.

**Updated** :  - when I remove the # characters from the file paths then the command works fine. But that is the condition and I cannot change it.

**Code executed from Java:**

```
param = "install list \\\"-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm\\\";

String commandToRunArr[]={"/bin/sh","-c", "/usr/local/bin/test.py" + " " + param};

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRunArr);
```

**Other information:**

/usr/local/bin/test.py is an executable .

**How I have tried to resolved the issue by modifying the command to run :**

**First command :** `/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/test.py install list \"-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm\"`

Error: ERROR: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

ERROR: sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Return Code 1

**Second command :** `/bin/sh -c -- /usr/local/bin/test.py install list \"-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm\"`

ERROR: /bin/sh: - : invalid option

ERROR: Usage:  /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...

ERROR:         /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...

Return Code 2

**Third command:** `'/usr/local/bin/test.py set priorityList "-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm"'`

ERROR: /bin/sh: - : invalid option

ERROR: Usage: /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...

ERROR:        /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...

Return Code 2

**Fourth Command:** `/usr/local/bin/test.py set priorityList "-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm"`

Error: error=2, No such file or directory

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Return Code -999

Comment: Instead of `String commandToRunArr[]={"/bin/sh","-c", "/usr/local/bin/test.py" + " " + param};`, use `String commandToRunArr[]={ "/usr/local/bin/test.py", param}`

Comment: Using `sh` adds serious security concerns. It's much worse than just being a correctness problem.

Comment: Do you have a working shell command that runs outside of Java? If not, that should be your first step

Comment: @that other guy - Please note that the problem is because of the # hach char, as the command runs perfectly without the # has char in filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was not with the python script nor Java code or with `/bin/sh`. It was the process of making the binary of the python script that was being used in the process of making the python script to executable in Makefile . The passed arguments to the executable had a check of allowed characters list which did not contain hash character # hence the argument passed to python was rejecting the argument which consists hash # character.

Answer (score 0):

Take the shell out of the loop. If your entire `param` string is exactly one argument:

```java
String commandToRunArr[]={"/usr/local/bin/test.py", param}
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRunArr);
```

If instead it's multiple arguments, put them in the array, divided exactly how you want (using only Java literal string syntax, no shell quotes or shell escaping). The below is one guess at what your actual intent was:

```java
String commandToRunArr[]={
  "/usr/local/bin/test.py",
  "install",                                     // sys.argv[1] in test.py
  "list",                                        // sys.argv[2] in test.py
                            // below string becomes sys.argv[3] in test.py
  "-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test.rpm:-i /export/home/test/ABC#XYZ#TEST/test2.rpm"
}
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRunArr);
```

Comment: Please check the fourth command used trying to solve the problem. There i find the error , no such file or directory. I forgot to mention which I will update in my question , that the First command works like a charm if O remove the # characters from the files' path